# Comparison using cross correlation

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, digital

I have 2 stereo audio files to compare.

Comparison of files include change in frequency, amplitude, phase shift

Code:

```
a = wavread("C:\Users\Narendranath\Desktop\Recordings\Release_2\Chirp.wav",[2, 100]);

b = wavread("C:\Users\Narendranath\Desktop\Recordings\Release_3\Chirp.wav",[2, 100]);

[cor1, lag1] = xcorr(a(2, :), b(2, :));            
subplot(1,1,1);            
plot2d(cor1(1,:));
```

I do not know how to proceed this further. Any ideas?

Comment: MATLAB?  Octave?  something else?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The question says `scilab`.

Comment: my eyes missed it.  i dunno scilab.

Comment: How are we supposed to debug your code without seeing your code? Even if we saw the code, the question would, I'm afraid, be off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stereo audio file will have 2 channels. You will need to select each channel separately and do cross-correlation. The Xcorr function understands only real or complex vectors as input but you are probably passing both channels at the same time.

If audio.wav is your file :

```
[y,Fs,bits]=wavread("audio.wav");Fs,bits
audio_channel1= y(:,1)
audio_channel2= y(:,2)
```

Here audio_channel1 & audio_channel2 are the vectors you need to cross correlate with the reference audio/signal.

Comment: Thank you!! But while for cross-correlation in scilab we use xcorr(x,y) where x and y are the two audio signal. Where to use audio_channel1 and audio_channel2 as arguments here

Comment: How to combine audio_channel1 & audio_channel2 into a single vector

Comment: To answer the second question : it might not be good idea to combine them. Rather you can either ignore one of the channels (if they are very similar) or get two xcorrelation outputs and see what fits your need. For 1st question in xcorr(x,y)... X is the audio_channel1 and Y is your reference signal for channel 1(or vice versa). If you have only one reference signal  you can repeat the process xcorr(audio_channel2,Y) , again Y is your reference signal for channel2.

Comment: a = wavread("C:\Users\Narendranath\Desktop\Chirp.wav",[2, 100]);

b = wavread("C:\Users\Narendranath\Desktop\Chirp.wav",[2, 100]);       cor1 = xcorr(a(2, :), b(2, :));   Now how can I compare the two waves to find the similarity

Comment: cor1 in your code gives the un-normalized cross correlation. If you normalise it, a value of 1 is where the signals are perfectly correlated. if you use [cor1,lag1]=xcorr(a(2,:),b(2,:) , lag1 gives you the lag. Ref: https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/xcorr.html
To solve your problem try to understand what is correlation and how it will help you rather than using code mechanically. please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371577/finding-the-difference-between-two-signals 
and https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measuring-signal-similarities.html